# How to add list of lists SQLite database Android studio

Tags: android, database, list, sqlite, android-studio

I want to work an application similar to this application so that it contains a list of the List

[image]

I have researched a lot I did not find explanations for only a simple data base containing a single list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change your database, than don't forget to change DATABASE_VERSION to bigger value.

Here is an example without foreign key:
You need to write `getChildListByParentId(int id)`

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "File_name.db"; // just use a name.


    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    private final String TABLE_LIST = "main_list";
    private final String TABLE_LIST_ID = "id";
    private final String TABLE_LIST_NAME = "name";

    private final String TABLE_CHILD_LIST = "child_list";
    private final String TABLE_CHILD_LIST_ID = "id";
    private final String TABLE_PARENT_LIST_ID = "parent_id";
    private final String TABLE_CHILD_LIST_NAME = "name";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String CREATE_MAIN_LIST_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LIST + "("
                + TABLE_LIST_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                + TABLE_LIST_NAME + " TEXT" + ")";

        String CREATE_TABLE_CHILD_LIST = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CHILD_LIST + "("
                + TABLE_CHILD_LIST_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                + TABLE_PARENT_LIST_ID + " INTEGER,"
                + TABLE_CHILD_LIST_NAME + " TEXT" + ")";

        db.execSQL(CREATE_MAIN_LIST_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_CHILD_LIST);
    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_LIST);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CHILD_LIST);

        onCreate(db);
    }


    public void addListItem(ParentListItem item) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(TABLE_LIST_NAME, item.getName());
        db.insert(TABLE_LIST, null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    public void addChildListItem(ChildListItem item) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(TABLE_CHILD_LIST_NAME, item.getName());
        values.put(TABLE_PARENT_LIST_ID, item.getParentId());
        db.insert(TABLE_LIST, null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    public void deleteParentItem(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_LIST, TABLE_LIST_ID + " = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(id) });
        db.close();
    }

    public void deleteChildItem(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_CHILD_LIST, TABLE_CHILD_LIST_ID + " = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(id) });
        db.close();
    }



    public List<ParentListItem> getAllParentListItem() {
        List<ParentListItem> result = new ArrayList<>();

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_LIST, null, null, null, null, null, null);

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            ParentListItem item = new ParentListItem();
            item.setId(getIntByColumName(cursor, TABLE_CHILD_LIST_ID));
            item.setName(getStringByColumName(cursor, TABLE_LIST_NAME));
            result.add(item);
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return result;
    }



    public int getIntByColumName(Cursor cursor, String tableColumn) {
        return cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(tableColumn));
    }


    public double getDoubleByColumName(Cursor cursor, String tableColumn) {
        return cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(tableColumn));
    }


    public String getStringByColumName(Cursor cursor, String tableColumn) {
        return cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(tableColumn));
    }


}
```

Comment: Can read more : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm

Comment: Thank you .. I'm going to try this

Answer (score 0):

You have to create two tables. One for the parents and other for childs.
Specify an unique id to parent item in first table and while adding children use that id to map them to their parent item.

Comment: Yes, this is what I do in the programming ios but I am new to Android programming and do not know how to link the two tables. I hope there is a link to explain it, if any. Thank you

Comment: CREATE TABLE FIRSTTABLE (id,name,age);

CREATE TABLE SECONTABLE (id,todo,parentID);

Now you can just fetch them by using id of parent table;
SELECT * FROM SECONDTABLE WHERE parentID = 1

Comment: Thank you .. I'm going to try this